# How to use ASP.NET Core Identity UserManager<ApplicationUser> through static method to get Identity User data from DB

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, usermanager

I have created an API (ASP.NET core 6) and I have also used Identity framework for user management.
Admin can make users active or inactive. so I want to check if the user is active or not
in each API call. So I have created an extension method and I call this static method in onAuthorization method in custom authorize attribute.
There I try to decode the token and get user Id from token. Using the user id I call the extension method and there
I want to get the user from DB and check the user status(active/inactive). However I am facing the problem of using UserManager (initializing) since it is
a static method. Please can somebody show me how to achive this?

Custom Authorize Attribute:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var result = AuthExtension.ValidateUserStatus(context.HttpContext);
        if(result)
            return;
        else
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
    }
```

Extension Method:

```
public static bool ValidateUserStatus(HttpContext context)
    {
        var user = context.User;
        var authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault();
        if(authHeader == null) return false;

        var token = authHeader.Split(" ")[1];
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var securityToken = handler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
        var userId = user.FindFirstValue("sid");

        var _userManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(new ApplicationDbContext(new DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>(), new HttpContextAccessor())), null, new PasswordHasher<User>(), null, null, null, null, null, null);
        var dbUser = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId).Result;
        if (dbUser == null) return false;
        if (dbUser.RecordStatus == Domain.Entities.Enums.RecordStatus.Deleted) return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the initializing step causes the issue. If you have configured Identity services in Program.cs, you can directly call it in your method. Here is the [reference link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Also, I think you can move the initializing step to the ***OnAuthorization*** method:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var userManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<UserManager<User>>();
    var result = AuthExtension.ValidateUserStatus(context.HttpContext, userManager);
    if (result)
        return;
    else
        context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
}
```

and change the Extension method to:

```
public static bool ValidateUserStatus(HttpContext context, UserManager<User> userManager)
{
    .
    .
    .
    //var _userManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(new ApplicationDbContext(new DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>(), new HttpContextAccessor())), null, new PasswordHasher<User>(), null, null, null, null, null, null);
    var dbUser = userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId).Result;
    if (dbUser == null) return false;
    if (dbUser.RecordStatus == Domain.Entities.Enums.RecordStatus.Deleted) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm so grateful for you answer. It saved me actually!. I spent a whole day for this. Thanks again.